# Rank should increase only for specific column values

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate

I have the Below data

```
Col1      COl2 
A         20-Mar-2020
B         22-Mar-2020
A         25-Mar-2020
B         28-Mar-2020
C         04-Apr-2020
D         10-Apr-2020
E         25-Apr-2020
```

In my output , i want to show the Rank in such a way that it increase only when the column values are A and C , also the date changes when the column value are A and C

My required output is

```
Rank    Col1   Col2
1       A      20-Mar-2020
1       B      20-Mar-2020
2       A      25-Mar-2020
2       B      25-Mar-2020
3       C      04-Apr-2020
3       D      04-Apr-2020
3       E      04-Apr-2020
```

Can anybody help me with this ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need two levels of `WINDOWS` function as follows:

```
select rnk, col1, 
       min(case when col1 in ('A', 'C') then col2 end) 
            over (partition by rnk) as col2
from
(select t.*,
       sum(case when col1 in ('A', 'C') then 1 else 0 end) 
            over (order by col2) as rnk
from t);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when col1 in ('A', 'C') then 1 else 0 end) over (order by col2)
from t;
```

Note:  This assumes that the date values are distinct (hidden time components).  If not, you may want:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when col1 in ('A', 'C') then 1 else 0 end) over (order by col2, col1)
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's query only covers the ranking, the 2nd part of the question requires:

```
max(case when col1 in ('A', 'C') then col2 end) 
over (order by col2)
```

If the order by column is different from the returned column:

```
last_value(case when col1 in ('A', 'C') then col2 end ignore nulls)
over (order by col2) -- might be any other column, too
```